# Convert datetime object into a string

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

I need to convert a `datetime` into a string using [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.datetime_as_string.html).

Is there another way to directly convert only one object to string that doesn't involve using the following function passing an array of `1` element (which returns an array too)?

```py
numpy.datetime_as_string(arr, unit=None, timezone='naive', casting='same_kind')
```

With this function, I can make the conversion, but I just want to know if there is a more direct/clean way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide an example array input and desired output?

Comment: I would like to avoid using this function so I don't need to pass an array. The idea is just to convert one DateTime object into a string.

Comment: @leticia if you need to work with numpy objects in the first place (an array of one element is still an array), what's wrong with using the above function?

Answer (score 0):

As we dont know what is inside of `arr`, I assume it is just `datetime.now()`

If so try this:

```
import datetime

datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

>>> '2022-07-28 10:27:34.986848'
```

If you need numpy version:

```
np.array(datetime.datetime.now(), dtype='datetime64[s]')

>>> array('2022-07-28T10:32:19', dtype='datetime64[s]')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to convert one numpy DateTime64 object into a string, here is the answer.

```py
import datetime

yourdt = yourdt.astype(datetime.datetime)
yourdt_str = yourdt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

that's it

Answer (score 0):

```py
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now() # current date and time

year = now.strftime("%Y")
print("year:", year)

month = now.strftime("%m")
print("month:", month)

day = now.strftime("%d")
print("day:", day)

time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print("time:", time)

date_time = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
print("date and time:",date_time)
```